# Owl crousal slider not working when loading data via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on some wordpress project and my owl content will load via ajax. Now, what happens, when i load content via ajax, it loads content but not show is slider. Here is javascript code that i have already done:

```
function runAjax(objects){
var $response;
$.ajax({
    url:wpAjaxUrl,
    async:false,
    cache:false,
    type:"POST",
    //data:{'action':objects.action,'product_id':objects.product_id},
    data:objects,
    dataType:"json",
    beforeSend:function(){
        $(".loader_div").show();
    },
    success:function(response){


        $response=response;
        //console.log($response.subcategory_products);
    },
    complete:function(response){
        if(objects.action=='get_product_images'){
            // var owl1=$("#owl-related-accessories");
            // owl1.data('owlCarousel').reinit();
            $.getScript("http://localhost/inox/wp-content/themes/inox/js/jquery.min.js");
            $.getScript("http://localhost/inox/wp-content/themes/inox/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js");
            $.getScript("http://localhost/inox/wp-content/themes/inox/owl-carousel/owl.carousel-related-accessories.js");
            $.getScript("http://localhost/inox/wp-content/themes/inox/js/owl.js");
        }
        $(".loader_div").hide();
    }
});
return $response;
```

}

There are so many ajax request so that i have created a general function for requesting ajax.I hope you understand well. Here you can see that i have reload all owl's javascript code.In the following code i have get ajax response and append in owl crousal div.

```
$("#owl-related-accessories").html($ajaxRes.relatedHtmlData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You something ommit, it is not only need to download script `$.getScript(` also is need to run it to take effects on new created elements with JS. See all calls of functions in your html page (`<script>` with `$( document ).ready(function() </script>` and without it but is functions of carousel) and after run AJAXA call it all in Browser JS console and see if it have effect. Also see in your browser js consle if no erros after you run Ajax, because error stop js script run in place where error ocur

Comment: I think i have write all necessary things.

Comment: If you will write all that is need you will not have these problem

Comment: recall all fuctions after ajax when js make changes in document that respond form owl Carousel. Is need to call all functions that is called whe document loaded in browser full when you type url . Also may be your ajax put code not in container that is need or change id or classes of html elements or other?

Comment: Why you comment that `var owl1=$("#owl-related-accessories");owl1.data('owlCarousel').reinit();` ?

Comment: You write - `i have reload all owl's javascript code` but I think in html you have some `code that is in ondocument ready` and you not recall it after make changes with JS?!

Answer (score 0):

`During ajax return` **success:** Define owl carousel there. Means after returning ajax success, define owl carousel there.

```
success: function(data) {

                //Return ajax success response here

                jQuery('#cross_container').html(data);

                //run owl Carousel here 

                jQuery('.cross-sell-box').owlCarousel({
                    items: 3,
                    loop: true,
                    margin: 10,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 1000,
                    autoplayHoverPause: true,
                    nav: true
                });
```